# javascript adding numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a function

```
function updateLensTotals() {
  var lensesTotalIs = 0;
  for (z = 0; z < lensesArray.length; z += 7) {
    if (lensesArray[z + 2]) {
      console.log(z + " lensesArray[z+2] is: " + lensesArray[z + 2] + " | ");

      if (isNaN(lensesArray[z + 2])) {
        console.log(lensesArray[z + 2] + " is not a number <br/>");
      } else {
        console.log(lensesArray[z + 2] + " is a number <br/>");
      }
      lensesTotalIs = parseFloat(lensesTotalIs) + lensesArray[z + 2];

      if (isNaN(lensesTotalIs)) {
        console.log(lensesTotalIs + " is not a number <br/>");
      } else {
        console.log(lensesTotalIs + " is a number <br/>");
      }
      console.log(z + " lensesTotalIs: " + lensesTotalIs + " | ");
    }
  }
  jQuery('#lensesTotalDue').html("£" + parseFloat(lensesTotalIs));
  return;
}
```

which produces this in the console

```
0 lensesArray[z+2] is: 19.99 | 
19.99 is a number <br/>
019.99 is a number <br/>
0 lensesTotalIs: 019.99 | 
cashPaid 0 chequePaid 0  cardPaid 0
0 lensesArray[z+2] is: 19.99 | 
19.99 is a number <br/>
019.99 is a number <br/>
0 lensesTotalIs: 019.99 | 
7 lensesArray[z+2] is: 15.99 | 
15.99 is a number <br/>
19.9915.99 is not a number <br/>
7 lensesTotalIs: 19.9915.99 |
```

There is a form which provides values of products.  I used 19.99 for the first run and 19.99 and 15.99 for the second run.

The first run everything works as expected.  The 19.99 is a number and can easily get added to the total.  But in the second run the total seems to suddenly be treated as a text stream.  I must be doing something daft but I can't see it.

thanks

Comment: `lensesTotalIs += +lensesArray[z+2];` (no need to parseFloat() lensesTotalIs again, but you need to parse the array value apparently). Adding a `+` is a shortcut to cast it to a number.

Comment: that worked great.  I originally had lensesTotalIs += but changed it in frustration!!  If you want to put an anser in I'll mark it up for you.

Comment: You can use this btw: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2ceh9rx7/ (not using `+=` to add wasn't the issue, the problem was you called `parseFloat` on the wrong summand ;))